# iTextSharp set document landscape (horizontal) A4

Tags: c#, itext

How can I set an A4 document in landscape (horizontal) format in iTextSharp?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can set the page size to a rotated A4. E.g. (assuming PDF, but should apply regardless):

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc;

// ...initialize 'doc'...

// Set the page size
doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

I've done this with PDF without trouble, haven't tried it with other doc types.

Comment: Crowder, Sir. I also want to change the `PDF` to `landscape mode` will the above code work ???

Comment: What is funny is that doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE) does not work, but the answer works.

Answer (score 21):

You can initialize a new document like that:

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

In this mode all pages will be in landscape mode.

To change the layout of the page inside the document you can use:

```
doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4); // for vertical layout
doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate()); // for horizontal layout
```