# iTextsharp landscape document

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to create Landscape PDF using iTextSharp but It is still showing portrait. I am using following code with rotate:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 150, 20);
FileStream msReport = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/PDFS/") + "Sample1.pdf", FileMode.Create);

try
{
    // creation of the different writers
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msReport);

    document.Open();

    PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 30f;


    PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;

    Font fontCategoryheader = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("Sales Manager: ", fontCategoryheader)));
        PdfPCell.BorderWidth = 0;
        PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            PdfPCell.BackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

        PdfPCell.PaddingBottom = 5f;
        PdfPCell.PaddingLeft = 2f;
        PdfPCell.PaddingTop = 4f;
        PdfPCell.PaddingRight = 4f;
        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
    }

    document.Add(PdfTable);
    document.NewPage();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

finally
{
    // we close the document 
    document.Close();
}
```

Please suggest solution.

Thanks.

Comment: can you check with  Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(150, 20); Document document = new Document(pageSize);

Comment: Check the already answered question, you may get the clue you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370427/itextsharp-set-a-document-horizontal-page-a4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTextSharp set document landscape (horizontal) A4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370427/itextsharp-set-document-landscape-horizontal-a4)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this

```
Document Doc = new Document(new Rectangle(288f, 144f), 10, 10, 10, 10);
Doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

you might also need this to expand a table to max width.

```
var _pdf_table = new PdfPTable(2); // table with two  columns
PdfPCell hc = new PdfPCell();
_pdf_table.WidthPercentage = 100; //table width to 100per
_pdf_table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 25, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate().Width - 25 });// width of each column
```

You must make sure that when setting the page size you do it before a call to `Doc.Open();`

Regards.

Comment: Hi Shoaib, No it is still showing same size. With landscape, will the width be greater than height or the text direction will become top to bottom or bottom to top ?

Comment: width become greater.. it won't rotate the content

Comment: check code i just added. btw code i shared is using itextsharp 4.1

Comment: *This won't change the first page if you have already made a new Document object. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17996334/1001328

Answer (score 11):

No need to initialize the Document and reset the page size...

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

...will do the trick.

(4.1.6.0)