# Rotate to landscape for first page when creating PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to rotate all pages in my document to landscape

i tried:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(mydoc, New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
mydoc.Open()
mydoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate())
... add rest of document and close ...
```

but only my 2nd page is landscape, the first is portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the page size *before* you open the document. The moment you invoke `mydoc.Open()` the first page is initialized and you can no longer change its rotation, size,...

Also: if *all* pages need to be rotated, why not create the document instance using the correct size and orientation from the start?

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

That way you don't have to change the size.