# Convert itextsharp PDF from portrait to Landscape mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have a **PDF** generation code which was previously downloaded in **Portait** mode and the code behind is shown below.

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
```

which was working properly.

Now I need the same PDF to be converted to Landscape mode, I googled it and found this code.

```
Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(288f, 144f), 10, 10, 10, 10);
doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

But still its displaying in Portrait mode.Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Document doc = new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(842,595), 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);`?

Comment: @mkl yeah its working now!!

Comment: Great, I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
```

for portrait PDF. The `PageSize.A4` is defined as

```
Rectangle A4 = new RectangleReadOnly(595,842);
```

Thus, one way to create a landscape PDF would be to use a `RectangleReadOnly` with switched width and height values:

```
Document doc = new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(842,595), 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
```

Alternatively a rotated version of the original rectangle should work, too:

```
Document doc = new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(595,842,90), 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
```

Comment: Haris' answer is simpler

Comment: @RicardoAppleton *"Haris' answer is simpler"* - that may be, but if you look at the *question*, you'll see that Haris' proposal is identical to one line the OP had tried and (for which reasons ever) was not happy with.

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
Doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is when you are giving it 10,10,10,10. how can you see it as landscape?? 
change it to as per you margins and try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040161/itextsharp-landscape-document)

Comment: remove this

    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);


and do 
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);

try it