# iTextSharp, page break in PDFPTable and define body size

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, itext

I want to know, how can I do make a page break in PDFPTable but I don't want it cut the table just after the table header ?

And I want to define a size to the body of my page but I don't know how can I make that can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

According [to this](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/86), no, you cannot manually force a page break within a table. Your primary alternatives are to either just make multiple tables or use `WriteSelectedRows`. If you are forcing a page break then you generally "know when" you want to do it so either option should work. Multiple tables allow you to still leverage iTextSharp's flow logic whereas `WriteSelectedRows` gives you more control but assumes you have calculated if things actually fit. See this for a [sample of using `WriteSelectedRows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601244/231316).

To control the document's size you can either use the [constructor to `Document`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079446/231316) which optionally takes a `Rectangle` and a margin or you can call [`SetPageSize` on the `Document`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2370504/231316) if you want to control it per-page.