# Getting Paper Size of a PDF

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to read / write PDF in our application. I am trying to get the paper size of a page to show in metadata window. I am using following code to do the same:

```
      // read PDF document into memory
      var pdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfPath);

      // if PDF document has more than one page, then try to get the page size from first page
      if (pdfDocument.Pages.Count > 0)
      {
        var pageSize = pdfDocument.Pages[0].Size.ToString();
      } // if
```

But every time it returns 'Undefined', I even tried to create A4 page document for MS Word. But still it returns 'Undefined'.

I also created a PDF from HTML but then also page size comes as undefined.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // create PDF config to generate PDF
      var config = new PdfGenerateConfig()
                   {
                     PageSize = PageSize.Letter,
                     PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
                   };

      // load the HTML file
      var html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\mohit\Desktop\Temp\Ekta\Test.html");

      // generate the PDF
      var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html,
                                         PageSize.Letter);

      // get the paper size of first page
      var size = pdf.Pages[0].Size;

      // save the pdf document
      pdf.Save(@"C:\Users\mohit\Desktop\Temp\Ekta\A13.pdf");

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Here is another question from SO that might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370427/itextsharp-set-document-landscape-horizontal-a4

Answer (score 0):

The properties you have to use are `Width` and `Height`. Convert them to millimeter or inch if you do not want to show the size in points.

The property `Size` is a convenient way to set standard page sizes for new pages as you can specify A4 or Letter. It will not be set for imported PDF files.