# iTextSharp streaming HTML Table to PDF with nowrap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am converting my HTML Table to PDF:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(GridHtml);
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A0, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Grid.pdf");
}
```

This works fine but I have some white-space (nowrap) after conversion.

How can I have no wrap on the `<td>` of my HTML table?

And also my table is very long, it has a lot of columns. What would be the best to extend the page or best practice for having a long table in width when its very long horizontally?

Here is GridHtml:

https://jsfiddle.net/2nyjhpaz/

Comment: What's `GridHtml` looks like? Include example HTML markups which you want to add `td white-space: nowrap` selector.

Comment: GridHtml is a string that has a full HTML table in it....I can provide tomorrow

Comment: Your use of the bounty system is admirable. Good luck.

Comment: It has been 2 days already. Still waiting for the HTML....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you work with iText5 and there might be troubles with recognising `white-space: nowrap` anyway and therefore it's possible to set your table preferences going through all the cells in your code after obtaining the table from the page elements:

```
// Setting a css file
ICSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
ICssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(cssStream);
cssResolver.AddCss(cssFile);

// HTML
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

// Pipelines
ElementList elements = new ElementList();
ElementHandlerPipeline pdf = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);

CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);
// XML Worker
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
// Transmitting the html file with the table
p.Parse(htmlStream);

// Obtaining the table
var table = elements[0];
var pdfTable = table as PdfPTable;

foreach (var c in pdfTable.Rows.SelectMany(r => r.GetCells()))
{
    c.NoWrap = true;
}
```

Here is the link to the [official documentation](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-convert-html-table-pdf) (though there are only examples written in JAVA) which I applied to my example.
The problem with the approach is that you're likely to be responsible for dealing with your cell widths like this ([How to define the width of a cell?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-define-width-cell)
):

```
 pdfTable.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 500, 500, 500, 500, 500 });
 pdfTable.LockedWidth = true;
```

Otherwise the cells might overlap with one another.

To define your page size in accordance to the table width and height you can do it the next way ([How to define the page size based on the content?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-define-page-size-based-content)):

```
var pdfDoc = new Document(new Rectangle(pdfTable.TotalWidth, pdfTable.TotalHeight), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
```

Comment: What is cssStream? what does it look like?

Comment: In this particular case it's just a stream of a resource in my test project containing all the styles for my html stream (I also store it as an embedded resource). I set it the next way: `var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); var cssStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PDFCreatorTestProject.styles.css"); var htmlStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PDFCreatorTestProject.table.html");`

Comment: You can avoid storing all your data in resources and get streams directly from strings like this: `var css = "<your style>";
            ICSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
            ICssFile cssFile;

            using (MemoryStream cssStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)))
            {
                cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(cssStream);
            }

            cssResolver.AddCss(cssFile);` The same way is possible for `htmlStream`.

Comment: Okay, ill give this a try

Comment: I am stuck on this part: p.Parse(htmlStream); how would I define htmlStream using my variable GridHtml?

Comment: It depends on what `GridHtml` is. If it's just a string then you should do it the same way as I depicted above, like this: `using (MemoryStream htmlStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GridHtml))) {  p.Parse(htmlStream); }`

Comment: Actually, you can do it in a way equal to your own example, that is to say, through the usage of `PdfWriter`: `var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream); pdfDoc.Open(); pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable); pdfDoc.Close();`, where `stream` is any kind of stream: `FileStream` or `MemoryStream` - it's up to you.

Comment: So define stream as `MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165847/discussion-between-user979331-and-oleg-safarov).

Comment: This is working very well....But I am having trouble setting the cell width...is there away to set the cell width to all cells? or better yet, apply 1 size to first row of cells and the another width for all other cells?

Answer (score 0):

## [Use HTML `<td>` nowrap Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp)

```
<td nowrap>No wrapped</td>
```

> The nowrap attribute of  is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.
> CSS syntax: `<td style="white-space: nowrap">`

Test example is here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_nowrap.

---

> What would be the best to extend the page?

You can use `Rotate()` to landscape the page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370427/itextsharp-set-document-landscape-horizontal-a4):

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc;

// ...initialize 'doc'...

// Set the page size
doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

Or use `RectangleReadOnly` for setting the size of height and width:

```
Document doc = new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(595,842,90), 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
```